# Get instance of caller (via reflection)

Tags: java, reflection, instance

is it somehow possible to get the instance object of the calling class?

```
class A{
    void foo(){
        Object o = getCaller(); //?? expect instance of B 
        long val1 = ..          // get val1 of o via reflection
        // do something where val1 is crucial
    }
}

class B{
    double val1 = Math.random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().callFoo();
    }

    void callFoo(){
        new A().foo();
    }
}
```

I know that I can find out calling class/method via stacktrace but I need the conrete instance to access instance variables (like val1 in example).

I know it's dirty but class B is in an unchangable library so that it's nearly impossible to pass the required field without rebuilding everything.

Comment: What if there is no instance? Why do you even need it?

Comment: No, you basically can't do this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the instance of the caller unless the instance is somehow passed to it, or stored in a collection.

To pass the instance you can do the following :

```
class A{
    void foo(Object caller){
        long val1 = ..          
        // do something where val1 is crucial
    }
}

class B{
    double val1 = Math.random();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().callFoo();
    }

    void callFoo(){
        new A().foo(this);
    }
}
```

The "this" keywork will pass the instance of the calling code to the foo method in Class A